# Phalcon install php.h file not found

Tags: phalcon

When i try install phalcon framework on mac os mavericks I see 1 error generated.

***lib/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:163:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found

Comment: I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php installed.

If you currently have it install make sure you do a `brew upgrade` this will update all homebrew links and should allow you to progress with the install.